# How to add current date and previous 7 days date in api automatically

Tags: python, api, rest, view, calendar

I want to add startDate, last seven days of the current date, and end date as today date automatically in API in python
can anyone help me?

```
response = requests.get('http://172.24.105.27:8092/Co=LT&StartDate=06-05-2022&EndDate=14-05-2022', headers=my_headers)
s = response.json()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.today()
start = (today - datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
end = today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

response = requests.get(f'http://172.24.105.27:8092/Co=LT&StartDate={start}&EndDate={end}', headers=my_headers)
s = response.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use datetime library provided by python to achieve that.

This is how your code will look like. I have intentionally made the code a bit long, so that you can understand what is happening on each line. This can undoubtedly be done is lesser lines of code.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

base_url = 'http://172.24.105.27:8092/Co=LT'

start_date_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
end_date_time = datetime.now()

url = f'{base_url}&StartDate={start_date_time.date()}&EndDate={end_date_time.date()}'

print(url)

response = requests.get(url, headers=<your_headers_dict_here>)
print(response)
```

Sample URL that got formed

```
http://172.24.105.27:8092/Co=LT&StartDate=2022-08-11&EndDate=2022-08-18
```